# Prompt to ask desired amount of lines. Why do I get "undefined" at the end each line?

Tags: javascript, undefined, prompt

Beginner here, eagerly trying to get my code to work. 
I need to ask the user how many lines of "lottery coupons" they want. After the prompt the code outputs seven randomly generated numbers, line by line, as I wanted. But after each line, I get "undefined".

Why is this? I know I'm not too far off...

```
var ask = prompt("How many lines?");

function numbers() {
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
        var line = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1;
        document.write(line + ' ');
    }
}

for(var x=0; x<ask; x++) {
    document.write(numbers() + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because your `numbers();` function doesn't have any defined return.

You can return an empty string. `return "";`

```
var ask = prompt("How many lines?");

function numbers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        var line = Math.floor(Math.random() * 39) + 1;
        document.write(line + ' ');
    }
    return "";
}
for (var x = 0; x < ask; x++) {
    document.write(numbers() + '<br>');
}
```

Comment: Alright! So functions always need some sort of return value in order to "document.write" them? Thank you for an easy explanation.

Comment: @user3465990 To put it simple if the function doesn't have a defined return it will return undefined. When you document.write the return of the function you need to have a defined return or it will output undefined, which in your case you define it as an empty string as is needed. You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 2):

numbers() returns undefined, so you don't want to output it.  Try:

```
var ask = prompt("How many lines?");

function numbers() {
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
        var line = Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1;
        document.write(line + ' ');
    }
}

for(var x=0; x<ask; x++) {
    numbers(); 
    document.write('<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `numbers` function isn't returning anything.

Here's an example with putting the numbers into an array and then joining them:

```
var ask = prompt("How many lines?");
function numbers() {
    var nums = [];
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
        nums.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*39)+1);
    }
    return nums.join(' ');
}
for(var x=0; x<ask; x++) {
    document.write(numbers() + '<br>');
}
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6SHJE/1/

Comment: Your return statement will terminate the loop. You don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the return value of calling `numbers` and then a line break element.

```
document.write(numbers() + '<br>');
```

The `numbers` function doesn't have a `return`statement , so it returns `undefined`.

You want:

```
numbers();
document.write('<br');
```